# Trying to submit html form data to excel

Tags: html, excel, go

I got success to write code to submit html form data as single excel row. But in my html form I want to submit multiple data which should be appended in single cell of excel but second part of data should start with new line in the same cell. Just like (ALT + Enter Operation). My html code is as below.

index.html

```
{{template "header"}}
<form method="POST">
    <label for="name">NAME</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    <br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;">
    <label for="gender">GENDER</label>
    <input type="text" id="gender" name="gender">
    <br>
    <label for="age">AGE</label>
    <input type="text" id="age" name="age">
    <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<br>
```

I tried with "style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;" but it wont help.

My golang code is as below.

```
func datasubmit(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
      nm := req.FormValue("name")
      ge := req.FormValue("gender")
      ag := req.FormValue("age")
      var data = M{"Name": nm, "GENDER": ge, "AGE": ag}  // i have used map type M map[string]interface{}
      tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.gohtml", data)
      f, err := excelize.OpenFile("./Book99.xlsx")
          if err != nil {
          fmt.Println(err)
          return
         }
      sheetName := f.GetSheetName(0)
      fmt.Println(sheetName)
      rows, err := f.GetRows(sheetName)
      rlast := len(rows)
      fmt.Println(rows)
      fmt.Println(rlast)
      f.SetCellValue(sheetName, fmt.Sprintf("A%d", rlast+1), data["Name"])
      f.SetCellValue(sheetName, fmt.Sprintf("B%d", rlast+1), data["GENDER"])
      f.SetCellValue(sheetName, fmt.Sprintf("C%d", rlast+1), data["AGE"])
      err = f.SaveAs("./Book99.xlsx")
       if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
       }
}
```

Can you please guide me to break first cell with multiple data start with new line.
ex jim;jam  ==> jim
jam  both in single cell but jam with new line in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appreciate your feedback and time given to resolve my query.

Finally, I achieved my goal with help of below code. It is slight complicated but yes its working for me and I hope it will be helpful for others too.

```golang
func datasubmit(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    nm := req.FormValue("name")
    ge := req.FormValue("gender")
    ag := req.FormValue("age")

    sliNm := strings.Split(nm, ";") // creating slice if ";" occur then it treat as another element of slice

    var final string // again creating string to fill "\n"
    for _, v := range sliNm {
        final += v
        final = final + "\n"
    }

    fmt.Println(final)

    var data = M{"Name": final, "GENDER": ge, "AGE": ag} // data as map
    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.gohtml", data)

    f, err := excelize.OpenFile("./Book99.xlsx")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    sheetName := f.GetSheetName(0)
    
    // Set cell A1 to Wrapp
    style, err := f.NewStyle(&excelize.Style{
        Alignment: &excelize.Alignment{
            WrapText: true,
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(sheetName)
    rows, err := f.GetRows(sheetName)
    rlast := len(rows)
    fmt.Println(rows)
    fmt.Println(rlast)

    f.SetCellStyle(sheetName, fmt.Sprintf("A%d", rlast+1), fmt.Sprintf("A%d", rlast+1), style) // setting cell style for newly creating cell with every iteration
    fmt.Println(data["Name"])
    f.SetCellValue(sheetName, fmt.Sprintf("A%d", rlast+1), data["Name"])
    f.SetCellValue(sheetName, fmt.Sprintf("B%d", rlast+1), data["GENDER"])
    f.SetCellValue(sheetName, fmt.Sprintf("C%d", rlast+1), data["AGE"])

    err = f.SaveAs("./Book99.xlsx")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

This code works for me. Lets say input is jim;jam; ==> my o/p is as below in single cell of excel.   jim
jam

Also, yes executing template is making no sense but i have created it just to see recently submitted data on website.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your query correctly I believe you are asking how to add a new line of text into an excel cell (you would use ALT+Enter to do this in the Excel application). Where the data comes from does not appear to be relevant to your question.

In Excel (on Windows) multiple lines in a cell are split by a line feed (char 0xA, or `\n` in go). However there is a slight complication in that Excel automatically sets the cell to "wrap" when you add a line break (if you don't do this the line break is there but not displayed).

Here is an example of how this can be implemented in Go; each time you run the application it will add a new line to cell A1. Note that I am not changing the cell height so you will need to do that to make the extra lines visible:

```golang
func main() {
    f, err := excelize.OpenFile("./Book99.xlsx")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    sheetName := f.GetSheetName(0)

    // Set cell A1 to Wrap
    style, err := f.NewStyle(&excelize.Style{
        Alignment: &excelize.Alignment{
            WrapText: true,
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := f.SetCellStyle("Sheet1", "A1", "A1", style); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Get cell value, add new name and save
    v, err := f.GetCellValue(sheetName, "a1")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%x\n", v) // Output as hex so you can see how the line break is encoded
    err = f.SetCellValue(sheetName, "a1", v + "\n" + "Joe Bloggs")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = f.SaveAs("./Book99.xlsx")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detail explanation. But my requirement is different. I am providing input from html form and after submit button every time it will add new rows of data in excel..  Ex, if I enter data in text box. ex. jim,jam; jimmy;  then output should be in single cell with jim, jam in single line and jimmy should start in next line within the same cell.

Comment: I understand that your requirement is more complex but your core issue appeared to be "how do I add multiple lines of text to a cell in Excel" (which I have answered). The above code should be fairly easy to implement within your `datasubmit` function. If this was not your issue then please clarify your question (aim for a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).